# How do you scope uniquenuess based on two values with Rails 3 validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an model, called Replay, that has 3 attributes, match_id, game_number, and uploader_id. Essentially, I would like a validation to enforce that an uploader does not upload a replay for a match with the same game number as a replay they have already uploaded for that match. I would like, however, for another user to be able to upload a replay for that match and game number.

The validation I am using now is:

```
validates :game_number, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :match_id }
```

But this does not take into account the uploader_id. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try: `scope: [:match_id, :uploader_id]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
validates :game_number, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: [:match_id, :uploader_id] }
```