# How do I ensure uniqueness across a set of attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Rails 3.2.8 and I want to ensure uniqueness across a set of attributes in 1 row of a table but I can have multiple rows with the same values. The validates_uniqueness_of validator doesn't seem to work for this. To give some context these are lottery number selections.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217391/how-do-you-scope-uniquenuess-based-on-two-values-with-rails-3-validations/10217486#10217486

Comment: Thanks jdoe. This is what I have in my model: 

validates :winning_numbers_date, uniqueness: { scope: [:winning_number_1, :winning_number_2, :winning_number_3,\
   :winning_number_4, :winning_number_5, :winning_number_6, :winning_number_bonus] }

But that's still not doing the trick. I can still enter 7 identical numbers.

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood you: `winning_number_1` just have to be uniq among other `winning_number_`-prefixed fields in one row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure `winning_number_X` != `winning_number_Y`, try:

```
# in your model

UNIQ_FIELDS = [:winning_number_1, :winning_number_2, :winning_number_3,
  :winning_number_4, :winning_number_5, :winning_number_6, :winning_number_bonus]

validate :numbers_uniquness

# ...    

def numbers_uniquness 
  unless UNIQ_FIELDS.map{|field| self[field] }.uniq.length == UNIQ_FIELDS.length
    errors[:base] << "Numbers have to be uniq" 
  end
end
```